# Get value of object field using variables to build the field name

Tags: json, object, google-apps-script

I am using a free currency converter API as shown in the code:

```
// Free Currency Converter
    url = 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_USD&compact=ultra';
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    rateEURUSD_FCC_JSON = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    rateEURUSD_FCC = rateEURPLN_FCC_JSON.EUR_USD;
    Logger.log('rateEURUSD_FCC = ' + rateEURUSD_FCC);
```

And that works well.
Now I want to use the same method but in a function taking currency1 and currency2 as inputs.

```
url = 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q='+Currency1+'_'+Currency2+'&compact=ultra';
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    fiatRate_FCC_JSON = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    fiatPairName = Object.keys(fiatRate_FCC_JSON);
```

I can see the name of the key created in the object but I do not know how to get the value of that element (that key?).

```
theValue = fiatRate_FCC_JSON.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I think I need to use currency1 and currency2 to build the name of the field I want to access but I do not know how to do this.

Can anyone help? 
Yes, I have tried looking on google and through the forum's search tool so please do not direct me back there if that would be your only contribution. Thanks.

EDIT:
This worked

```
theValue = fiatRate_FCC_JSON[Currency1+'_'+Currency2];
```

Thanks Tanaike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
theValue = fiatRate_FCC_JSON[Currency1+'_'+Currency2];
```

If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Answer (score 0):

I think that can help you also

```
var theValue = fiatRate_FCC_JSON[fiatPairName[0]]
```